# jQuery Slideshow Issues - Slideshow Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-cycle2

I am trying to create a webpage which goes through all contents in a folder, and presents its contents in the form of a slideshow. Below is my basic code where I try to get the results from `glob()` and display all the .jpg files within the folder `pictures/`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">

body{
background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="cycle-slideshow"
    data-cycle-fx="scrollHorz"
    data-cycle-loader=true
    data-cycle-timeout="0"
    data-cycle-prev="#prev"
    data-cycle-next="#next"
    >
        <?php
        $folder = 'pictures/';
        $filetype = '*.jpg';
        $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
        $count = count($files);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            echo '"'; echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'" width="80%" height="60%"/>'; echo '"';
        }   
        ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake, never use script tag with id , which is wrong i think. simply remove script tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>



<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.cycle2.js"></script>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" >
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style type="text/css">

body{
background-color: white;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>


<div class="cycle-slideshow">
    <div class="cycle-prev" style="position:relative;float:left;cursor:pointer">PREV</div>
    <div class="cycle-next" style="position:relative;float:right;cursor:pointer">NEXT</div>
        <?php
        $folder = 'pictures/';
        $filetype = '*.jpg';
        $files = glob($folder.$filetype);
        $count = count($files);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {
            echo '<img src="'.$files[$i].'" width="80%" height="60%"/>';
        }   
        ?>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You can make images array in script tag if you want to add more slides dynamically later. Hope above works

Comment: I still receive the same error when doing this fix.

Comment: That's the weird thing.. I don't get any error messages, just nothing shows up correctly aside from the background.

Comment: there may be error, if slide is not running, for that in chrome press CTRL+SHIFT+I to see console and reload page

Comment: Hi I have fixed that, it works here, please copy whole code given by me.

Comment: Okay, now how do I let my pictures shift off a click of a button? I have many large pictures which are too much memory to be loaded at once

Comment: Never upload large pictures to the web, before upload by resizing and reduce size, buttons controls are added in code, but you can write your CSS to style and position them